# Adjusting gridlines on a 3D Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm getting ready for a presentation and I have some example figures of 3D matplotlib figures. However, the gridlines are too light to see on the projected images.
[image: example 3D image]

I tried using the grid-method that works for 2D figures:

```
points = (5*np.random.randn(3, 50)+np.tile(np.arange(1,51), (3, 1))).transpose()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], points[:,2])
ax.view_init(elev=0., azim=0)
ax.set_ylim([0, 60])
ax.set_zlim([0, 60])
ax.set_xlim([0, 60])
ax.set_zlabel('Cytokine')
ax.set_ylabel('Parameter')
ax.grid(linewidth=20)
```

But that doesn't seem to work for 3D figures. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind having all the lines thicker then you could adjust the default rc settings.

Given a graph such as:

[image]

We can add:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
```

To increase the default line width of all lines, giving a result of:

[image]

Alternatively, if you feel this looks ugly, you could use:

```
ax.w_xaxis.gridlines.set_lw(3.0)
ax.w_yaxis.gridlines.set_lw(3.0)
ax.w_zaxis.gridlines.set_lw(3.0)
```

to adjust the line width of each axis to 3.0, producing:

[image]

In order to update the colour, so the grid-lines really pop, you could add:

```
ax.w_xaxis._axinfo.update({'grid' : {'color': (0, 0, 0, 1)}})
ax.w_yaxis._axinfo.update({'grid' : {'color': (0, 0, 0, 1)}})
ax.w_zaxis._axinfo.update({'grid' : {'color': (0, 0, 0, 1)}})
```

Which produces:

[image]

The methods are pretty hacky, but as far as I am aware there is no simpler way of achieving these results!! Hope this helps; let me know if you require any further assistance!

Comment: @JudoWill - you should accept this answer if it fixes your problem!

Comment: This does not work for me in matplotlib version 3.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be exposed. Looking over the source, the key internal variable is call `_AXINFO` which we can override by careful subclassing.

[image]

Add this code after your figure is created, and style it with the dict `custom_AXINFO`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d as axis3d

# New axis settings
custom_AXINFO = {
    'x': {'i': 0, 'tickdir': 1, 'juggled': (1, 0, 2),
          'color': (0.00, 0.00, 0.25, .75)},
    'y': {'i': 1, 'tickdir': 0, 'juggled': (0, 1, 2),
          'color': (0.20, 0.90, 0.90, 0.25)},
    'z': {'i': 2, 'tickdir': 0, 'juggled': (0, 2, 1),
          'color': (0.925, 0.125, 0.90, 0.25)},}

class custom_XAxis(axis3d.Axis):
    _AXINFO = custom_AXINFO

class custom_YAxis(axis3d.Axis):
    _AXINFO = custom_AXINFO

class custom_ZAxis(axis3d.Axis):
    _AXINFO = custom_AXINFO

class custom_Axes3D(Axes3D):
    def _init_axis(self):
        '''Init 3D axes; overrides creation of regular X/Y axes'''
        self.w_xaxis = custom_XAxis('x', self.xy_viewLim.intervalx,
                                    self.xy_dataLim.intervalx, self)
        self.xaxis = self.w_xaxis
        self.w_yaxis = custom_YAxis('y', self.xy_viewLim.intervaly,
                            self.xy_dataLim.intervaly, self)
        self.yaxis = self.w_yaxis
        self.w_zaxis = custom_ZAxis('z', self.zz_viewLim.intervalx,
                            self.zz_dataLim.intervalx, self)
        self.zaxis = self.w_zaxis

        for ax in self.xaxis, self.yaxis, self.zaxis:
            ax.init3d()

# The rest of your code below, note the call to our new custom_Axes3D

points = (5*np.random.randn(3, 50)+np.tile(np.arange(1,51), (3, 1))).transpose()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10)) 
ax = custom_Axes3D(fig)
```

**This is monkey-patching at it's worst, and should not be relied upon to work for later versions.**

Fixing the facecolors was easier than the grid lines, as this requires an override of one of the `__init__` methods, though it could be done with more work.

It does not seem difficult to expose this to the end user, and as such I can imagine that this may be fixed in later versions.

Comment: It looks like now you can do ax.w_xaxis.plane.set_color((1,0,0)); ax.w_xaxis.plane.set_alpha(0.5). It looks like it ignores the alpha channel in set_color but uses the one in set_alpha.

Answer (score 1):

If to lighten the background of grid, can use setting the pane color more light (eg:white) using Axes3DSubplot object as below.

```
ax.w_xaxis.pane.set_color('w');
ax.w_yaxis.pane.set_color('w');
ax.w_zaxis.pane.set_color('w');
```

Or else to highlight the grid lines further, can updated grid color parameter of plot.

```
plt.rcParams['grid.color'] = "black"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this to change the linewidth:

```
plt.rcParams['grid.linewidth'] = 2
```

[image: plotted by the code below:]

Full scripts to plot the figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

points = (5*np.random.randn(3, 50)+np.tile(np.arange(1,51), (3, 1))).transpose()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], points[:,2])
#ax.view_init(elev=0., azim=0)
ax.set_ylim([0, 60])
ax.set_zlim([0, 60])
ax.set_xlim([0, 60])
ax.set_zlabel('Cytokine')
ax.set_ylabel('Parameter')
plt.rcParams['grid.linewidth'] = 4   # change linwidth
plt.rcParams['grid.color'] = "black" # change color
```